# How do I freeze a specific (older) version of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many versions of rails installed on my system (of 2 & 3) but I want to put version 2.3.11 in the vendor folder ...

rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.3.11

tries to connect to http://dev.rubyonrails.org/archives/rails_2.3.11.zip

and times out, is there another way?

Comment: I just wound up finding the branch in the rails git repository,  downloading the zip file of that https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v2.3.11, and unzipping to the vendor/rails directory

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a specific version of rails you can go to the applications gemfile and replace the rails gem with the gem desired.e.g.

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '2.3.11'
```

then run bundle install
as for the vendor folder you might try

```
gem install rake --install-dir /rails_dir/vendor/gems
```

to create a gem repository for your vendor directory. If neither of these work you might be looking for a gem freeze in which case try http://gemsonrails.rubyforge.org/. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain an older app and have to do this occasionally. The easiest way I've found is to install the gem locally to your system and then use:

```
rake rails:freeze:gems RELEASE=2.3.11
```

Comment: just installs the latest version of rails for me ... in this case version 3.0.9 :\

Comment: Should be `rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.3.15`